# Terraform plan hangs on Mac

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create a very simple EC2 instance in AWS using Terraform:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.16"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.2.0"
}

provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-west-2"
}

resource "aws_instance" "app_server" {
  ami           = "ami-830c94e3"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
```

I have created a valid AWS profile `terraform` with which I can login fine through AWS CLI. I've executed terraform from my Mac terminal:

```
export AWS_PROFILE=terraform
export TF_LOG=TRACE
terraform init
terraform plan
```

It just hangs forever. Since I enabled trace logging, I can see it going in a loop as shown here:

```
2022-08-13T14:16:47.961+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-aws_v4.26.0_x5: [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go-v2] retrying request STS/GetCallerIdentity, attempt 4
2022-08-13T14:16:47.961+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-aws_v4.26.0_x5: [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go-v2] Request
2022-08-13T14:16:47.961+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-aws_v4.26.0_x5: POST / HTTP/1.1
2022-08-13T14:16:47.961+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-aws_v4.26.0_x5: Host: sts.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
2022-08-13T14:16:47.961+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-aws_v4.26.0_x5: User-Agent: APN/1.0 HashiCorp/1.0 Terraform/1.2.6 (+https://www.terraform.io) terraform-provider-aws/dev (+https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws) aws-sdk-go-v2/1.16.10 os/macos lang/go/1.18.4 md/GOOS/darwin md/GOARCH/amd64 api/sts/1.16.4
2022-08-13T14:16:47.961+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-aws_v4.26.0_x5: Content-Length: 43
2022-08-13T14:16:47.961+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-aws_v4.26.0_x5: Amz-Sdk-Invocation-Id: 6143fa8c-4e0c-4f5f-9594-fbe52b5ed650
2022-08-13T14:16:47.962+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-aws_v4.26.0_x5: Amz-Sdk-Request: attempt=4; max=25
2022-08-13T14:16:47.962+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-aws_v4.26.0_x5: Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=xxx/20220813/us-west-2/sts/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-request;content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=xxxyyy
2022-08-13T14:16:47.962+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-aws_v4.26.0_x5: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
2022-08-13T14:16:47.962+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-aws_v4.26.0_x5: X-Amz-Date: 20220813T131647Z
2022-08-13T14:16:47.962+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-aws_v4.26.0_x5: Accept-Encoding: gzip
2022-08-13T14:16:47.962+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-aws_v4.26.0_x5: 
2022-08-13T14:16:47.962+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-aws_v4.26.0_x5: Action=GetCallerIdentity&Version=2011-06-15
2022-08-13T14:16:48.320+0100 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "aws_instance.app_server (expand)" is waiting for "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"]"
2022-08-13T14:16:48.321+0100 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"] (close)" is waiting for "aws_instance.app_server (expand)"
2022-08-13T14:16:48.321+0100 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "root" is waiting for "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"] (close)"
2022-08-13T14:16:53.321+0100 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "root" is waiting for "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"] (close)"
2022-08-13T14:16:53.321+0100 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "aws_instance.app_server (expand)" is waiting for "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"]"
2022-08-13T14:16:53.322+0100 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"] (close)" is waiting for "aws_instance.app_server (expand)"
2022-08-13T14:16:58.323+0100 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "aws_instance.app_server (expand)" is waiting for "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"]"
2022-08-13T14:16:58.323+0100 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"] (close)" is waiting for "aws_instance.app_server (expand)"
2022-08-13T14:16:58.323+0100 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "root" is waiting for "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"] (close)"
2022-08-13T14:17:03.324+0100 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "root" is waiting for "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"] (close)"
2022-08-13T14:17:03.324+0100 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"] (close)" is waiting for "aws_instance.app_server (expand)"
2022-08-13T14:17:03.324+0100 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "aws_instance.app_server (expand)" is waiting for "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"]"
2022-08-13T14:17:08.324+0100 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "aws_instance.app_server (expand)" is waiting for "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"]"
2022-08-13T14:17:08.324+0100 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"] (close)" is waiting for "aws_instance.app_server (expand)"
2022-08-13T14:17:08.324+0100 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "root" is waiting for "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"] (close)"
2022-08-13T14:17:13.325+0100 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "root" is waiting for "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"] (close)"
2022-08-13T14:17:13.325+0100 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "aws_instance.app_server (expand)" is waiting for "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"]"
2022-08-13T14:17:13.325+0100 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"] (close)" is waiting for "aws_instance.app_server (expand)"
```

Comment: Have you run `terraform init` prior to running plan?

Comment: Yes - I have executed `terraform init` successfully

Comment: Can you add the `required_providers` block to the question?

Comment: Can you try with a version prior to 4.26? There might be a bug as it was released 2 days ago.

Comment: Are you running the `darwin_amd64` build of Terraform and the AWS provider under Rosetta 2 on an Apple Silicon (`darwin_arm64`) Mac? Rosetta's emulation isn't perfect, and I've heard about it getting "stuck" in similar ways to this before.

Comment: I have the same issue, @kms333 did you find any solution?

Comment: I have the same issue as well but with azurerm...

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR - Your DNS servers need updating.** I was banging my head against the same issue for the last few hours today.

If you do a `dig https://sts.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` and nothing comes up, you are most definitely hitting a DNS resolution error.

Go to Network > Select your network (Wifi or whatever the name) > DNS. In the DNS, add DNS servers from Google or OpenDNS.

These are the DNS servers from Google - `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` (Refer:
https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using)

DNS servers from OpenDNS - `208.67.222.222` and `208.67.220.220`
(Refer: https://www.opendns.com/setupguide/)

After this if you do run the same dig command, it should resolve. And so should your `terraform plan`.

Highlighting that this is not an issue with terraform or aws.